# Create new custom QtQuick view to use with model

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qabstractitemmodel

I created a custom view to arrange photos in a seamless grid, like Google Photos does (see below). My view is based on `QAbstractItemView` (Qt Widgets based). I would like to port this to QtQuick, in order to take advantage of hardware acceleration, animations, and touch.

[image]

QtQuick has some views inheriting from `Flickable` that it you can use with models, like `ListView` and `GridView`. Is there a way to create my own custom view? Things I thought about:

- Create a proxy model that knows the width of the view, and lays out the images in rows. Then just use a Flickable with Repeaters to read from that model, and lay out the images. Downsides: Adding thousands of photos like this, without dynamically loading and recycling, is going to take too many resources.
- Similar, but use a ListView on each "row" I put together above. Use the recycling capability of the ListView to not load too many rows. I would have to disable the selection function and roll my own on top. Could work, but seems very hacky.
- Go to the source of the ListView, and implement something similar: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp.html . `QQuickListView` inherits from (internal) `QQuickItemView` which does a lot of heavy lifting, and probably some things I don't need. This seems like the most correct way, but is a huge amount of work.

What's my best option here?

Comment: I don't think option 2 is hacky at all and would work well. You would want to preprocess your images so the ListView model is ordered sets of images where each set is the images to show on each row and have each row be a RowLayout of Images. It should scale well.